# How to get different data in ng-repeat ? - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS and I have created an web app.

I don't know how to get values from one specific link.

I have an admin page where I have all users and I get them using ng-repeat

```
<div ng-repeat="user in allusers">
```

But I have created routes for example user level and I have added them to http://mylink.com/user_level/john@doe.com -- (that's example so I will get user level via user email)

Comment: Is the first portion of the URL, constant? meaning, is it always going to be 'http://mylink.com/rest/user_level'?

Comment: Also, does the user object contain the user's email?

Comment: Maybe you should include the user level property into your user object when you fetch your users list. Seems inefficient to call your user level endpoint for every user.

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach would be to have the service that retrieves the users, send the user's level in the user object itself.

But, if this is not an option and you have to make separate service calls to get the user's level, this is how you would do this.

```
  function getUserLevels(users) {
    for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {
      getUserLevelForUser(users[i]);
    }
  }

  function getUserLevelForUser(user) {
    $http.get(BASE_URL + '/' + user.email)
      .then(function (response) {
          user.userLevel = response.data.userLevel;
        });
  }

  getUserLevels($scope.users);
```

Since I do not have access to your API, I've created a plunker app that invokes the Open Movie Database API. In this demo, instead of the user's level, I will be fetching a movie's director. Also, instead of using the user's email in the url, I will be using the movie name.

**See [working plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/TJC6hLFaufaoZfTxxd70?p=preview)**